# Connection issue in Hadoop MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop

In a Hadoop MapReduce program, I am trying to read JDBC connection details from `connection.properties` file, that is also in proper classpath.

Code:

```
public synchronized Connection getConnection() {
    return getDetails(); // inside try catch block
}   

public Connection getDetails() throws SQLException, IOException {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("connection.properties");
    props.load(in);
    in.close();
    String drivers = props.getProperty("jdbc.drivers");
    if (drivers != null) {
        System.setProperty("jdbc.drivers",drivers);
    }
    String url = props.getProperty("jdbc.url");
    String username = props.getProperty("jdbc.username");
    String password = props.getProperty("jdbc.password");
    return DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
}
```

But when running my driver main program it gives an error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: connection.properties (No such file or directory)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Is this piece of code getting executed in Main or Mapper or Reducer..?Which phase?

Comment: It is a part of simple class name dbconnection.

Comment: In which phase this code gets executed..? Main or inside mapper..?

Comment: extended outformat class calls getConnection() method.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run the MapReduce that uses properties file, you need to package it with your code, and instead of using the traditional reading the file streams from local system, you can read it from the jar you already built

reading properties from jar:

```
InputStream stream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("foo.properties"))
```